# Jquery Validate require at least 1 checkbox if text field has a value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Struggling with a validation scenario with jQuery Validate. I need at least 1 checkbox to be checked if a text field has a value. I have found how to require at least one checkbox in a group on their own, but not based on a value from a different field.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="x">
<input type="checkbox" name="b" value="y">
<input type="checkbox" name="c" value="z">
<input type="text" name="textfield">
```

At least one of the three checkboxes must be checked if there is any value at all in 'textfield'. If there is no value in 'textfield' the checkboxes can be checked or not - not required.

Comment: For this scenario, you need all three to have the exact same `name` attribute.  In that case, at least one of the three would be required.

Comment: For the second part, you would use a `depends` attribute to toggle the `required` rule on the checkboxes.

Comment: Not possible to have all be the same name. I was hoping that something with a class would work, possibly with require_from_group.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y2tmgf6e/

Comment: yes, `require_from_group`  stand by

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s62h8or1/

Comment: My only problem with the question is that no attempt was made at a solution.

Comment: I did try a few things but none worked, which is why I posted. But your last jsfiddle looks promising. Checking on my code now.

Comment: I appreciate that, but ideal questions contain the attempted solution in order to prevent duplication of work as well as teaching others.  For example, had you said you needed all three names to be different, I would not have made the first fiddle.

Comment: Understood, I appreciate your assistance none the less. Your code seems to do the trick. Add as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<form id="myform">
    <input type="checkbox" class="foo" name="a" value="x">
    <input type="checkbox" class="foo" name="b" value="y">
    <input type="checkbox" class="foo" name="c" value="z">
    <input type="text" name="textfield">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            a: {
                require_from_group: function() {
                    if ($('[name="textfield"]').is(':filled')) {
                        return [1, ".foo"];
                    }
                }
            },
            b: {
                require_from_group: function() {
                    if ($('[name="textfield"]').is(':filled')) {
                        return [1, ".foo"];
                    }
                }
            },
            c: {
                require_from_group: function() {
                    if ($('[name="textfield"]').is(':filled')) {
                        return [1, ".foo"];
                    }
                }
            },
            textfield: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertBefore(element);
        }
    });
});
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/s62h8or1/**

Answer (score 0):

You can check this ,hope it helps you

```js
let checkBox_i = $("input[name='a']");
let checkBox_ii = $("input[name='b']");
let checkBox_iii = $("input[name='c']");

let text = $("input[name='textfield']");

$(':input').on('input', validateInput)

function validateInput() {
  let a = text.val().trim();
  let b = checkBox_i.is(':checked');
  let c = checkBox_ii.is(':checked');
  let d = checkBox_iii.is(':checked');

  //checks if text extsts and checks any one of checkbox is checked
  if (a.length > 0 && (b || c || d)) {
    //your code 
    $('.validStatus').text('valid input');
  } else {
    //uncheck checkbox if input is removed
    checkBox_i.prop('checked', false);
    checkBox_ii.prop('checked', false);
    checkBox_iii.prop('checked', false);

    //alert user for invalid input
    $('.validStatus').text('');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="x">
<input type="checkbox" name="b" value="y">
<input type="checkbox" name="c" value="z">
<input type="text" name="textfield">

<div class='validStatus'></div>
```

Comment: He specifically asked about how to accomplish this using the jQuery Validate plugin.